# Paste Values only when pasting into Excel

Tags: excel, vba, paste

Trying to set up a workbook where certain sheets(which are dynamically named) restrict pasting to Values Only.  Tried referring to a sheet with identical formatting to keep the correct cell format when pasting via ctrl-v, but it isn't working.  Is there an easier way?  Here's the code I'm trying:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim rng As String
rng = ActiveCell.Address


Application.ScreenUpdating = False


ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Formatting").Visible = xlSheetVisible
Sheets("Formatting").Select
Cells.Select
Selection.Copy


Sheets.ActiveSheet.Select
Cells.Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False


ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Formatting").Visible = xlSheetHidden 


Range(rng).Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub
```

Comment: `Sheets.ActiveSheet.Select` will select the sheet named "Formatting", because of the previous line `Sheets("Formatting").Select`

Comment: Hi. In almost every case, you can avoid using Select in vba code. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros . Then you will not have to manage the visibility of the sheet. One possibility would be to Unprotect the sheet before copying and protect it back after.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want. No need to unhide a sheet if you're not `Select`ing it:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim currently_activated As Range
    Set currently_activated = Selection
    With Worksheets("<<enter the name of the sheet here>>")   '<-- change this to name of sheet
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Sheets("Formatting").Cells.Copy
        .Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
            SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        currently_activated.Select
    End With
End Sub
```